# obtener lastInsertId con PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estoy tratando de obtener el último registro de la base de datos y me responde con 0 (CERO).. `lastInsertId();`.

Está es mi conexión a la BD:

```
class conexion{

    public static function conectar(){
        try {
                $link = new PDO(''.DRIVER.':host='.SERVER.';dbname='.DATABASE, USERNAME, PASSWORD, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES  \'UTF8\''));
                $link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            return $link;

            }catch(PDOException $e){
                echo "Fallo la conexión: " . $e->getMessage();
                }
            }
}
```

Y esta es la consulta:

```
 public static function mdlGuardarTitulos($tabla, $Anun_Registrado, $Anun_Fecha, $Anun_Titulo){

    $consulta = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO tblanuncios( AutoIncrID, Anun_Registrado, Anun_Fecha, Anun_Titulo,  ) VALUES ( :AutoIncrID, :Anun_Registrado, :Anun_Titulo)");
    $AutoIncrID = null;

    $consulta -> bindParam(":AutoIncrID", $AutoIncrID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $consulta -> bindParam(":Anun_Registrado", $Anun_Registrado, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $consulta -> bindParam(":Anun_Fecha", $Anun_Fecha, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $consulta -> bindParam(":Anun_Titulo", $Anun_Titulo, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $consulta -> execute();
    $lastInsertId = Conexion::conectar()->lastInsertId();
    return  $lastInsertId;


    $consulta -> close();
    $consulta = null;

 }
```

Pero no estoy seguro si `Conexion::conectar()->lastInsertId();` es correcto me retorna un 0, el registro si se realiza correctamente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considero que es mejor que guardes una referencia del objeto de conexión que acabas de crear, en vez de llamar de nuevo al método `conectar`.

```
public static function mdlGuardarTitulos($tabla, $Anun_Registrado, $Anun_Fecha, $Anun_Titulo){

    $pdo=Conexion::conectar();
    $consulta=$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tblanuncios(Anun_Registrado, Anun_Fecha, Anun_Titulo,  ) VALUES (:Anun_Registrado, :Anun_Titulo)");

    $consulta -> bindParam(":Anun_Registrado", $Anun_Registrado, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $consulta -> bindParam(":Anun_Fecha", $Anun_Fecha, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $consulta -> bindParam(":Anun_Titulo", $Anun_Titulo, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    if ($consulta -> execute()) {
        $lastInsertId = $pdo->lastInsertId();
    }else{
        //Pueden haber errores, como clave duplicada
         $lastInsertId = 0;
         echo $consulta->errorInfo()[2];
    }   

    $consulta -> close();
    return  $lastInsertId;
}
```

**Otras cosas que he optimizado:**

- En el `INSERT` se pueden omitir las columnas de tipo `auto_increment`
- Se recupera el último id insertado únicamente en caso de que la consulta sea exitosa, si no se imprime un mensaje de error y se devuelve `0` (esto es opcional)
- Se cierra `$consulta` antes del `return`. Todo lo que se pone después de `return` nunca se ejecuta.
- `close()` y `null` son redundantes. He dejado sólo `$consulta->close()`.

---

#### Optimizando la conexión PDO

El constructor de PDO admite como último parámetro un array de opciones. Puedes entonces crear un array que contenga todas las opciones de configuración, así evitas una llamada suplementaria a `setAttribute`. En ese mismo array conviene indicar que el atributo `ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` es `FALSE`. Es un nivel de seguridad adicional, para desactivar totalmente las preparaciones emuladas que pueden conducir en ciertos escenarios a ataques de Inyección SQL.

```
class Conexion{

    public static function conectar(){
        try {
                $pdoOptions = array(
                                        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE, 
                                        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                                        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES  \'UTF8\''
                                    );

                $link = new PDO(''.DRIVER.':host='.SERVER.';dbname='.DATABASE, USERNAME, PASSWORD, $pdoOptions);
                return $link;

        }catch(PDOException $e){
                echo "Fallo la conexión: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

El juego de caracteres (charset), se puede establecer también en la cadena de conexión (DSN), [como se explica aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.construct.php#113498). En ese caso, la siguiente línea: <s>`PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES  \'UTF8\''`</s> debe ser eliminada en  `$pdoOptions`.

Comment: Funciono perfecto solo me da _errror_ si cierro la conexión antes del **return**, si hago el **return** antes si funciona perfecto, gracias @A. Cedano

Comment: @daniel no veo por qué haya que cerrar la conexión. ¿? El objeto `$pdo` se cerrará solo cuando salgas del contexto (función) que lo utiliza, y eso ocurre precisamente cuando el `return` ocurre. En cualquier caso, me alegro de que la respuesta te haya ayudado a resolver el problema. Por favor, cuando sea posible l◔_◔: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) en el Centro de Ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

```
$consulta = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO tblanuncios( AutoIncrID, Anun_Registrado, Anun_Fecha, Anun_Titulo,  ) VALUES ( :AutoIncrID, :Anun_Registrado, :Anun_Titulo)");
$AutoIncrID = null;

$consulta -> bindParam(":AutoIncrID", $AutoIncrID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$consulta -> bindParam(":Anun_Registrado", $Anun_Registrado, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$consulta -> bindParam(":Anun_Fecha", $Anun_Fecha, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$consulta -> bindParam(":Anun_Titulo", $Anun_Titulo, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$consulta -> execute();
$id = $consulta->lastInsertId();
return  $id;


$consulta -> close();
$consulta = null;
```