# ¿Cómo obtengo el lastinsertID del ultimo registro que hizo mi modelo en PHP?

Tags: php, php7, pdo, model-view-controller

Buenas tardes con todos necesito ayuda , soy relativamente nuevo en programación y me encuentro ya sufriendo un par de días con esta parte del código, lo que quiero hacer es que cuando llamo al modelo *MDlPublicartrabajo* que hace el *insert* de una tabla llamada publicaciones, quisiera traerme el ultimo registro con un *lastinsertID* y meterla como variable en mi *foreach* en el ultimo campo justo donde dice'52' puse 52 para ensayar con el id de uno de los registros de la tabla publicaciones y si inserta en mi bd, pero quisiera insertar   siempre el ultimo registro de mi modelo *MDlPublicartrabajo* muchas gracias de antemano.

Este es el código del controlador:

```html
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

class ControllerPublicacion{
    
    
      /*mostrar publicaciones */
    
    static public function ctrMostrarDatosPublicaciones($item,$valor){
        
        $tabla="publicaciones";
        
        $respuesta=ModeloPublicaciones::MdlMostrarPublicaciones($tabla,$item,$valor);
        return $respuesta;

    }   

     /*----REGISTRO DE PUBLICACIONES----*/
    static public function ctrCreatePublicacion(){
        
        
        if(isset($_POST["idusuario"])){
             if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $_POST["idusuario"]))
                {
                 $tabla="publicaciones";
            
                 
                $datos=array("idusuario" => $_POST["idusuario"],
                             "duracion" => $_POST["duracion"],
                             "titulo" => $_POST["titulo"],
                             "especialidad" => $_POST["especialidad"],
                             "niveltrabajador" => $_POST["niveltrabajador"],
                             "descripciontrabajo" => $_POST["descripciontrabajo"],
                             "complejidadtrabajo" => $_POST["complejidadtrabajo"],
                             "tipopresupuesto" => $_POST["tipopresupuesto"],
                             "rango" => $_POST["rango"],
                             "rangominimopresupuesto" => $_POST["rangominimopresupuesto"],
                             "rangomaximopresupuesto" => $_POST["rangomaximopresupuesto"],
                             "presupuestofijo" => $_POST["presupuestofijo"]
                            );
               
                 $respuesta=ModeloPublicaciones::MdlPublicarTrabajo($tabla,$datos);

                                    $conn=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=bdtrabajo","root","");
                 $especialidad = $_POST["especialidad"];
                 
                          foreach ($_POST['habilidades'] as $habilidad) {
             
        $queryhabilidad="insert into habilidadpublicacion (id,habilidad,idespecialidad,idpublicacion) VALUES (null,'$habilidad','$especialidad','52')"; 
                              
                              if ($resultadoM = $conn->query($queryhabilidad)){  

                     echo'<script>
            
           Swal.fire({
  type:"success",
  title: "!El trabajo se ha guardado correctamente!",
 showConfirmButton: true,
 confirmButtonText: "Cerrar",
 closeOnConfirm: false
  
})
             
           .then((result)=>{
            
            if(result.value){
            window.location= "publicacion";
            
            }
            
            });
            
            </script>';
                              }
                          }
             }
            else{ 
                
            echo'<script>
            
           Swal.fire({
  type:"error",
  title: "!Oops algo salio mal!",
 showConfirmButton: true,
 confirmButtonText: "Cerrar",
 closeOnConfirm: false
  
})
            
           .then((result)=>{
            
            if(result.value){
            window.location= "inicio";
            
            }
            
            });
            
            </script>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: El código debe ir como texto, por favor elimina la imagen y pega el código que veas que es relevante. ;)

Comment: Si amigo tienes razon ya pege el codigo de mi controlador, gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Obtener lastInsertId con PDO](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/205989/obtener-lastinsertid-con-pdo)

Comment: que tal juan rivera, si revise esa publicacion , pero si me retorna el ultimo id en mi modelo , pero como lo llamo o reutilizo esa variable en mi controlador y esque lo que quiero es insertarlo como variable en el foreach justo reemplazarlo por el '52'.te agradecería mucho amigo.